# https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1 not found?

Tags: powershell

on running below powershell script:

```
&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}
```

Getting Error:
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
At line:1 char:17
+ &{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.gith ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

On hitting "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1" it says not found. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Nope, I get a 404 too.

Comment: Here's a copy that work as of today: https://github.com/nurtenkovacheva/DnvmInstall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DNVM](https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm) project is discontinued:

> ## DNVM
>
> #### This repository is obsolete and no longer used or maintained.
>
> DNX and DNVM have been replaced by the new .NET CLI. See:
>
> http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/
>
> http://github.com/dotnet/cli
>
> As a result, we're not accepting anymore changes to this project. Please file any new issues on http://github.com/dotnet/cli.

Comment: How I can build my solution through TFS online portal if I have to implement .Net CLI. ..

Comment: The best way to get an answer is to create a new, different question.